# Do Wronskians have the intermediate value property?

Tags: real-analysis, determinant, wronskian

I wonder if the following is true:

> **Conjecture:** Let $I \subset \Bbb R$ be an open interval and $f, g: I \to \Bbb R$ be differentiable functions. Then the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian)
> $$
> W(f,g) =\begin{vmatrix}f &g \\f' & g'\end{vmatrix} = f g' - f'g
> $$
> is a Darboux function.

A [Darboux function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#Darboux_function) is a real-valued function $f$ which has the “intermediate value property”: for any two values $a$ and $b$ in the domain of $f$, and any $y$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, there is some $c$ between $a$ and $b$ with $f(c) = y$.

**Motivation and thoughts:**

- In [Does there exists two differentiable functions $f, g$ on $I$ such that $W(f, g) (x) >0$ on $A$ and $W(f, g) <0$ on $I\setminus A$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4490472/42969) it what proved that

  > If the Wronskian takes both positive and negative values on an interval, then it must be zero somewhere.

  and my conjecture would be a natural generalization.

  However, I do not yet see how the case of an arbitrary intermediate value $y$ can be reduced to the special case of $y = 0$ as the intermediate value.
- The conjecture is (trivially) true if both $f$ and $g$ are *continuously* differentiable, since then $W(f, g)$ is continuous. So the interesting case is that $f$ and $g$ are just assumed to be differentiable.
- Derivatives have the Darboux property, that covers the case that $f$ or $g$ is constant, e.g. $W(1, g) = g'$.
- Sums and products of Darboux functions are not necessarily Darboux functions (see for example [The sum of Darboux is a Darboux function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/330677/42969)). So even if all terms in $f g' - f'g$ have the intermediate value property, there is no immediate way to conclude the conjecture.

**A (failed) proof attempt:**

Assume that $w = W(f, g)$ does not take a value $y \in \Bbb R$, and consider the sets
$$
A = \{ x \in I \mid w(x) > y \} \, , \, B = \{ x \in I \mid w(x) < y \} \, .
$$
If we can show that both $A$ and $B$ are open then one of them must be empty (since $I$ is connected), and we are done.

If $f(x_0) \ne 0$ then we can define $h(x) = y \int_{x_0}^x f(t)^{-2} dt$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$, and
$$
 W(f, g) -y = f^2 \left( \frac gf - h\right)'
$$
shows that $W(f, g) -y$ does not change its sign near $x_0$, so that $x_0$ is an interior point of $A$ or of $B$.

A similar argument works if $g(x_0) \ne 0$. However, other than [in my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4490486/42969), one can not exclude the case $f(x_0) = g(x_0) = 0$. That is where my I am stuck in my current proof attempt.

Comment: Why can’t the product rule be used on $-fg$? To show its a derivative.

Comment: @VioletFlame: The derivative of $-fg$ is $-f'g - fg'$, and not equal to $W(f, g)$.

Comment: Yes but it’s close enough. Maybe something can be done.

Comment: They don't have to be open. Consider $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$, $g(x) = 1$, $y = 1/2$ - $0 \in B$, but it's not an inner point of $B$.

Comment: @LostinSpace: No. As in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4490486/42969, the idea is to prove the openness from the Darboux theorem, here applied to $\left( \frac gf - h\right)'$. That works as long as $f(x_0) \ne 0$ or $g(x_0) \ne 0$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wronskian of two differentiable functions may not have Darboux property. Below the conformation due to **Józef Banaś; Wagdy Gomaa El-Sayed**

Let $I=[0, 1]$  . Consider two functions $f, g $ defined by

$f(x) =\begin{cases}x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^4})&x\neq 0\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

$g(x) =\begin{cases}x^2 \cos(\frac{1}{x^4})&x\neq 0\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

For $x=0$ , $W(f, g) (0) =0$

For $x\neq 0$ ,
$\begin{align}W(f, g) (x) &=\begin{vmatrix} \sin(\frac{1}{x^4}) & \cos(\frac{1}{x^4})\\2x\sin(\frac{1}{x^4})-\frac{4}{x^3} \cos(\frac{1}{x^4})&2x\cos(\frac{1}{x^4})-\frac{4}{x^3} \sin(\frac{1}{x^4})
  \end{vmatrix}\\&=\frac{4}{x}\end{align}$

Hence $x\to W(f, g) (x) $ doesn't have the Darboux property.

---

$\color{red}{\textbf{  Theorem}}:$

> Let $f, g: I \to\Bbb{R}$  be functions differentiable on the interval
> $I$.  Assume that the set $ Z_f $(or $Z_g$) has no accumulation
> points, and $Z_f \cap \overline{ Z_g} = \emptyset$   (or $
>  \overline{Z_f} \cap{Z_g} = \emptyset$). Then $W(f,g)$ has the Darboux
> property on $I$.

Source : **BANAS, J.—EL-SAYED, W. G.: Darboux property of the Wronski determinant, Math. Slovaca $45 (1995), 57–61.$**  (Online available [here](https://eudml.org/doc/32307).)